# Trigger onclick event with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to trigger an `onclick` event via ***Chrome Developer Tools*** that will check all checkboxes on the page and also trigger the `onclick` event of all checkboxes on the page.

Here is a sample checkbox on the page:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="ctl00_ContentAreaHolder1_uctlLocationSelectionControl_AccountStructureTreeView.HandleCheck(this,'p_686660',4);" name="checker_p_686660">
```

Here is my code to check all checkboxes on the page:

```
(function() {
    var aa= document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i =0; i < aa.length; i++){
        if (aa[i].type == 'checkbox')
            aa[i].checked = true;
    }
})()
```

The only thing I cannot figure out is how to trigger the `onclick` event when the checkbox is checked. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to do that:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    $(this).trigger('click');
    // Will check all the checkbox and trigger the event
});
```

or simply:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    $(this).click();
    // Will check all the checkbox and trigger the event
});
```

or you can do it, using your code:

```
(function() {
    var aa= document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i =0; i < aa.length; i++){
        if (aa[i].type == 'checkbox')
            aa[i].click()
    }
})()
```

Comment: the code that begins with `var aa= document.getElementsByTagName` works for me. However, I am in need of more help! After all of the checkboxes are checked after running this code, another set of checkboxes appear that also need to be checked with the first set of checkboxes REMAINING checked. So I added the condition `if (aa[i].type == 'checkbox' && !aa[i].checked)` to the code. However, when I run this, the page seems to freeze and it does not check the new set of checkboxes. Is there something I am doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For checking all the checkboxes:

```
 $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
        });
```

For triggering to check all:

```
 $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
            $(this).trigger('click');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checker_p_686660">
```

Jquery Code

```
$('input').on('change', function(){

    if( $(this).prop('checked', true) ){
        alert('checked');
    }

})
```

Working Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2p64P/1/